# JavaScript fails to do AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm creating a form that can send the data through email using PHP and display a lightbox effect using JavaScript. Because I can't refresh the page, I decided to send the data to PHP using AJAX, however I can't get the code to do AJAX call. I founded this code on internet, I could use it as it is, but when I implemented it to my page, it just didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
var time_variable;

function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
   var xmlHttp = false;
   try {
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")  // For Old Microsoft Browsers
}

catch (e) {
   try {
     xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
   }
 catch (e2) {
   xmlHttp = false   // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
 }
}
  if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //For Mozilla, Opera Browsers
  }
   return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();   //xmlhttp holds the ajax object

function ajaxFunction() {
   var getdate = new Date();  //Used to prevent caching during ajax call
   if(xmlhttp) { 
   var txtname = document.getElementById("email");
       xmlhttp.open("POST","contactScript.php",true); //calling testing.php using POST method
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       xmlhttp.send("email=" + txtname.value); //Posting txtname to PHP File
   }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      }
      else {
          alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
      }
   }
}
```

Every time I run the code, I always stumble to that alert.

Maybe worth to mention that I gather the email data from a text input field with the id=email and I have no intention do update any field, except for displaying the lightbox effect.

Any help will be appreciated.

here's the PHP code (contactScript.php):

```
<?php
$field_email = $_POST['email'];

$mail_to = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
?>
```

not sure if this would help, but i suspect there's something wrong with my submit button:

```
    <form id="contactform" class="rounded" method="post" name="EmailForm">      

    <div class="field">
        <input type="text" id="email" class="input" name="email"    placeholder="your email address" />
        <a href = "javascript:submitForm()" onclick = "ajaxFunction();" class="button"> Submit </a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: What actually happens? What error you recieve?

Comment: ...and have you defined `getXMLObject()`? That syntax looks a bit odd to me, why would you have an object called `getXMLObject`? Surely you would have a function called `getXMLObject()` or an object called `XMLObject`...

Comment: i always get the alert dialog box. even though, the php script which sends the the data from the input field to my email, works.

Comment: @user1052291 Then your `contactScript.php` file returns a status code of something other than 200. Please post the contents of that file.

Comment: @DaveRandom I've added the PHP file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would lay that code out:

```
var time_variable;

function getXMLObject() {
  var xmlHttp = false;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    // For Mozilla, Opera Browsers and newer IEs
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  try {
    // For Old Microsoft Browsers
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e2) {
      // No ajax available
      xmlHttp = false;
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function ajaxFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var xmlHttp, postStr;
  // Get an AJAX object
  xmlHttp = getXMLObject();
  if (!xmlHttp) {
    alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support AJAX");
    return;
  }
  // Initialise the request
  xmlHttp.open("POST", "contactScript.php", true);
  // Define the callback function
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState < 4) {
      return;
    }
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; 
    } else {
      alert("Server responded with error code "+xmlHttp.status+"\n\nPlease try again");
    }
  };
  // Set the correct header for POST forms
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  // Make the POST string
  postStr = "email="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
  // Send the request
  xmlHttp.send(postStr);
}
```

I suspect you will still get an error, but the above code will tell you what that error actually is (HTTP status code) so you can debug your PHP script.

Comment: How are you calling the `ajaxFunction()`? What is the HTML?

Comment: i'm calling it through a link that got styled as a button

Comment: So sort of `<a href="javascript:ajaxFunction();">Do it</a>` type thing?

Comment: @gaban I think I see the problem. What is your `submitForm()` function doing? Whatever it is, I suspect it shouldn't be doing it. Try changing `<a href = "javascript:submitForm()" onclick = "ajaxFunction();" class="button"> Submit </a>` to `<a href = "javascript:void(0);" onclick = "ajaxFunction();" class="button"> Submit </a>`

Comment: ah! i see, it works now. thanks @DaveRandom. initially i want it to behave like a form input button kind of thing where the text field will automatically empty after the submit button is pressed. i'll see if i can do that without the submitForm()

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls go through multiple states. Your if() call immediately jumps to error alert, regardless whether the current state is actually an error.

E.g.:

```
0. instantiated, not initialized
1. initialize/opened
2. send() called, no response
3. receiving data, text/body not available
4. all data received
```

Your handler gets called ANYTIME the readystate changes, and since the first change is to reach stage 0, your error alert is called.

Comment: This is actually not correct, the code is in the correct set of `if`s, although it's not that obvious because it is spaced badly.